# Display a record from one table that occurs the most times on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have this problem where I want to display information from one table (in this case it's a basic table of accounts with account descriptions), the table has multiple records. I want to only display the information for the record in this Accounts table, that is called the most times on another table. I've got these two queries working in SQLS2019:

```
select GLA.AccountNo, AccountDescription
from GLAccounts GLA join InvoiceLineItems LI on GLA.AccountNo = LI.AccountNo 
group by gla.AccountNo, AccountDescription;


select TOP 1 AccountNo, Count(*) [Number of Line Items]  
from InvoiceLineItems 
group by Accountno
order by [Number of Line Items] desc
```

So individually they work as expected - I get all the info from my accounts page I want. And if I run the second query I get one result - the account that has the most invoice line items attached to in the other table. I need to link these two queries, and I cannot figure it out. I've tried various ways of trying to use query 2 as a subquery in a where/having block, I've tried joining the tables in different arrangements but can't get it to work.

I want to be able to run this query so that it just returns the AccountNo, and Description columns from the GLAccounts table based on which AccountNo has the most invoices in the InvoiceLineItem table. It's super confusing, and I think maybe I'm actually overthinking it and need something simpler that I'm missing?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results as formatted text (not images).

Comment: Sorry, not sure what this message means. I don't have any images in my post and there isn't any sample data.

Comment: Your job it to create a [mre] i.e. create some sample data the represents your problem, and show that to us along with your desired results. Actual data is much clearer than a text description. Ideally your sample data would be in DDL+DML format allowing us to copy and paste out and test your query directly.

Comment: _which AccountNo has the most invoices in the InvoiceLineItem table_ Be very careful about your requirements, your schema, and your goal. You are counting line items, not invoices. Line items are at a level below invoice - at least in most schemas. Unfortunately your description is inconsistent since you also refer to counting line items. Those are very different entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is pretty much there, if I understand correctly:

```
select top (1) GLA.AccountNo, gla.AccountDescription
from GLAccounts GLA join
     InvoiceLineItems LI
     on GLA.AccountNo = LI.AccountNo 
group by gla.AccountNo, gAccountDescription
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: How did I not think of this. This is so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you are trying to get AccountNo that have max raws from InvoiceLineItems. I use CTE (common table expression) to calculate number of items for everyone Accountno and then find max from it.

```
with list_account_with_count_items as (
    select AccountNo, Count(*) [Number of Line Items]  
    from InvoiceLineItems
    group by Accountno
)
select top(1) -- if you have more then 1 raw with same max_count_items
 GLA.AccountNo, AccountDescription, lawci.[Number of Line Items]
from GLAccounts GLA
join list_account_with_count_items lawci on GLA.AccountNo = lawci.AccountNo
where lawci.[Number of Line Items] = (
    select max([Number of Line Items])
    from list_account_with_count_items
)
```

Comment: This works (after having removed the "," between the two statements), but I'm not sure I understand how it works, or how I could have come to this solution. Appreciate it, though! Guess I have some reading to do on WITH statements

Comment: Its called a common table expression.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking to add the line item count to the list of accounts.  You could try something like this

```
select GLA.AccountNo, AccountDescription, count(*) as [Number of Line Items] 
from GLAccounts GLA join InvoiceLineItems LI on GLA.AccountNo = LI.AccountNo 
group by gla.AccountNo, AccountDescription
order by count(*) desc;
```